# C# WPF Button Error Click-Event in second WPF-Window (Dialog)

Tags: c#, wpf, button, click, touch

Im am new here, and english is not my native language. So forgive me
typing and spelling errors.

I have a problem (right, why should I ask a question if I dont have one).

My project is in C# and WPF, my OS in Win10. I have two Windows:

Window 1 -> MainWindow

Window 2 -> Selfdesigned Keypad (Textbox, Buttons)

When I run the program in Debug-Mode and Standalone with an mouse as Input-Device, everything works like charm.

But when I use a Touch-Screen, I get a problem.
In the MainWindow everything works fine, all Buttons work like I want
them to, but when I open the second Window I can not Tap the Buttons.
No Button-Click-Event gets fired. I know the way WPF handles Touch (Search for Touch-Events, then rerun everything with Mouse-Events). If I hack the Buttons like mad (5-10 times) everything works finde and I can use all Buttons without a problem. Close the second window and start it again -> same error.

I tried to set the focus on an button -> no dice.

Info: The second windows starts as a Dialog. I think this is an relevant information.

If I disable Tablet-Mode, everything works (but features like scrolling through grids with the finger like on phone doesnt work anymore).

Do you have an idea what is wrong?

Thanks very much!

Edit: What a huge Mistake. I doomed the code and didnt catch that.
So here we go:

With a Button I call the second window as Dialog like This:

```
try
        {
            Fenster.Fenster_Numpad Bildschirmtastatur = new Fenster.Fenster_Numpad("Position X:", "123");
            if (Bildschirmtastatur.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                string result = Bildschirmtastatur.Ergebnis;
            }

        }
        catch
        {

        }
```

And here ist the c# Code for the Window2:
You see I experimented with PreviewTouchDown and PreviewMousedown.

```
public partial class Fenster_Numpad : Window
{


    public class_edit class_edit_instanz = new class_edit();


    public string Ergebnis = "";

    public Fenster_Numpad(string Titel = "Numpad", string vorbelegung = "")
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this.class_edit_instanz;

        Numpad.Title = Titel;
        class_edit_instanz.Edit_String = vorbelegung;


    }




    private void Button_Enter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Ergebnis = class_edit_instanz.Edit_String;
            this.DialogResult = true;
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }

    private void Button_Del_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int selection_safe = TextBox_Wert.SelectionStart;

            if (TextBox_Wert.SelectionStart == 0 && TextBox_Wert.SelectionLength == 0)
            {
                class_edit_instanz.Edit_String = class_edit_instanz.Edit_String.Remove(TextBox_Wert.SelectionStart, class_edit_instanz.Edit_String.Length);
                TextBox_Wert.SelectionStart = selection_safe;
            }
            else if (TextBox_Wert.SelectionLength >= 1)
            {
                class_edit_instanz.Edit_String = class_edit_instanz.Edit_String.Remove(TextBox_Wert.SelectionStart, TextBox_Wert.SelectionLength);
                TextBox_Wert.SelectionStart = selection_safe;
            }
            else
            {
                class_edit_instanz.Edit_String = class_edit_instanz.Edit_String.Remove((TextBox_Wert.SelectionStart - 1), 1);
                TextBox_Wert.SelectionStart = selection_safe - 1;
            }

        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }


    private void Button_Plus_Minus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            if (class_edit_instanz.Edit_String.Contains("-"))
            {

                int selection_safe = TextBox_Wert.SelectionStart;

                class_edit_instanz.Edit_String = class_edit_instanz.Edit_String.Remove(0, 1);

                TextBox_Wert.SelectionStart = selection_safe - 1;
            }
            else
            {

                int selection_safe = TextBox_Wert.SelectionStart;

                class_edit_instanz.Edit_String = class_edit_instanz.Edit_String.Insert(0, "-");

                TextBox_Wert.SelectionStart = selection_safe + 1;
            }

        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }



    private void Button_Eingabe_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            Button Button_Eingabe = (Button)sender;

            // Wenn nichts markiert wurde (oder ein oder mehrere Zeichen) diese zunächst löschen
            if (TextBox_Wert.SelectionStart == 0 && TextBox_Wert.SelectionLength == 0)
            {
                class_edit_instanz.Edit_String = class_edit_instanz.Edit_String.Remove(TextBox_Wert.SelectionStart, class_edit_instanz.Edit_String.Length);
            }
            else if (TextBox_Wert.SelectionLength >= 1)
            {
                int selection_safe2 = TextBox_Wert.SelectionStart;
                class_edit_instanz.Edit_String = class_edit_instanz.Edit_String.Remove(TextBox_Wert.SelectionStart, TextBox_Wert.SelectionLength);
                TextBox_Wert.SelectionStart = selection_safe2;
            }

            int selection_safe = TextBox_Wert.SelectionStart;

            class_edit_instanz.Edit_String = class_edit_instanz.Edit_String.Insert((TextBox_Wert.SelectionStart), Button_Eingabe.Content.ToString());

            TextBox_Wert.SelectionStart = selection_safe + 1;



        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }






    public class class_edit : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _Edit_String = "";

        public string Edit_String
        {
            get
            {
                return _Edit_String;
            }
            set
            {
                _Edit_String = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Edit_String");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }

    }

    private void Button_Plus_Minus_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            if (class_edit_instanz.Edit_String.Contains("-"))
            {

                int selection_safe = TextBox_Wert.SelectionStart;

                class_edit_instanz.Edit_String = class_edit_instanz.Edit_String.Remove(0, 1);

                TextBox_Wert.SelectionStart = selection_safe - 1;
            }
            else
            {

                int selection_safe = TextBox_Wert.SelectionStart;

                class_edit_instanz.Edit_String = class_edit_instanz.Edit_String.Insert(0, "-");

                TextBox_Wert.SelectionStart = selection_safe + 1;
            }

            e.Handled = true;

        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }

    private void Button_Plus_Minus_PreviewTouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            if (class_edit_instanz.Edit_String.Contains("-"))
            {

                int selection_safe = TextBox_Wert.SelectionStart;

                class_edit_instanz.Edit_String = class_edit_instanz.Edit_String.Remove(0, 1);

                TextBox_Wert.SelectionStart = selection_safe - 1;
            }
            else
            {

                int selection_safe = TextBox_Wert.SelectionStart;

                class_edit_instanz.Edit_String = class_edit_instanz.Edit_String.Insert(0, "-");

                TextBox_Wert.SelectionStart = selection_safe + 1;
            }

            e.Handled = true;

        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }



}
```

}

Comment: uh, where's the code?

Comment: Updated! I dont know how I could screw this one up! The most importent part of the post... Thanks for the Info!